# vb 2022 - word - How to get full formated value of a BuildingBlock

Tags: visual-studio, ms-word, buildingblocks

I'm working with Visual Basic (2022) and Word (2013). I have a "Building Blocks.dotx" file in which I've add some QuickParts like 'sua' (BuildingBlock Name) for 'Signos de uncoartrosis'. All of them were added to 'General' category.
I would like to implement a solution without word application. For this I would like to save all of my QuickParts on a SQL Database.

So, the first step would be to read the QuickParts on my template and showed them into a RTB control. That's because some text are in bold fonts.

Rigth now I can read 255 characters of the BuildingBlock value, without RTF format and save it to my table:

```
        Dim wordApp As Word.Application = Nothing
        Dim document As Word.Document = Nothing
        Dim objBB As Word.BuildingBlock = Nothing
        Dim objTemplate As Word.Template
        Dim Cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;User Id=sa;Password=xxxxx;")

        Cn.Open()
        Try
            'create new instance
            wordApp = New Word.Application() With {.Visible = False}

            objTemplate = wordApp.Templates.Item(1)

            Dim cnt As Integer
            Dim cant As Integer = 0
            For cnt = 1 To objTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries.Count
                objBB = objTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries.Item(cnt)
                'objBB.
                If objBB.Category.Name = "General" Then
                    cant += 1
                    txtCodigo.Text = objBB.Name
                    rtbValor.Text = objBB.Value
                    Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AutoTexts (Nombre, Texto) VALUES (@Nombre, @rtfData)", Cn)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nombre", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = objBB.Name
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@rtfData", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = objBB.Value
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End Using

                End If
            Next
            Debug.Print(cant)
            Cn.Close()


        Catch ex As Exception
            'ToDo: add desired code

            Debug.WriteLine($"Error (ModifyWordDoc) - {ex.Message}")
        Finally
            If document IsNot Nothing Then
                document.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges)
            End If

            If wordApp IsNot Nothing Then
                wordApp.Quit()
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub
```

After that I was trying another approach. I try to insert de BB in a Word document, the copy and paste formatted text into a RTB. That works ok:

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim wordApp As Word.Application = Nothing
        Dim document As Word.Document = Nothing
        Dim objBB As Word.BuildingBlock = Nothing
        Dim objBBT As Word.BuildingBlockType = Nothing

        Dim objTemplate As Word.Template = Nothing

        wordApp = New Word.Application() With {.Visible = True}
        document = wordApp.Documents.Add(Template:="D:\SistemaClaudio\LeeTemplate-Autotextos\BB.dotx")

        Dim paramBBType As Word.WdBuildingBlockTypes = Word.WdBuildingBlockTypes.wdTypeQuickParts

        Dim paramBBCategory As String = "General"

        Dim paramBBName As String = "codopat"

        wordApp.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks()

        wordApp.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks()

        objTemplate = wordApp.Templates(2)

        Dim TemplateName As String = objTemplate.Name

        objBBT = objTemplate.BuildingBlockTypes.Item(paramBBType)

        objBB = objTemplate.BuildingBlockTypes.Item(paramBBType).Categories.Item(paramBBCategory).BuildingBlocks.Item(paramBBName)

        rtbValor.Text = objBB.Value
        objBB.Insert(document.Sections(1).Range)

    End Sub
    Private Sub rtbValor_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles rtbValor.KeyDown
        If (e.Control = True And e.KeyCode = Keys.V) Then
            Dim s As String = Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Rtf)
            rtbValor.Rtf = s
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

I press the command button and the full BB text is written on a word document, then I copied that and Paste into RTB and from there I could read it and save into my database table.
I could automate the CTRL-C and CTRL-V steps programmatically, but I'm wondering how to get RTF format from a QuickPart building block.